# Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':classpath'. Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.5

Tags: android, reactjs, gradle, native

how do i fix this even after installing gradle 8.5:

> Could not determine the dependencies of null.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
> > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.5.
> Required by:
> project :
> > No cached version of com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.5 available for offline mode.
> > No cached version of com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.5 available for offline mode.
> > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.5.
> Required by:
> project : > project :gradle-plugin
> > No cached version of com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.5 available for offline mode.
> > No cached version of com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.5 available for offline mode.

trace.`